# Trying to add the values of certain keys in my array to use in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, associative-array, reduce

I have an array of objects. One particular key/pair I want to add the total of accumulated storage.

`"AllocateStorage": 200,`+ `"AllocateStorage": 585,`+ `"AllocateStorage": 103547,`= `104,242`

```js
[{
  "MonitoringState": "disabled",
  "State_Code": 16,
  "State_Name": "running",
  "EbsOptimized": false,
  "EnaSupport": true,
  "AllocateStorage": 200,
  "SourceDestCheck": true,
  "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
  "SriovNetSupport": "None",
  "StateReason_Code": "None",
  "StateReason_Message": "None"
},
{
  "MonitoringState": "disabled",
  "State_Code": 16,
  "State_Name": "stopped",
  "EbsOptimized": false,
  "EnaSupport": true,
  "AllocateStorage": 585,
  "SourceDestCheck": true,
  "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
  "SriovNetSupport": "None",
  "StateReason_Code": "None",
  "StateReason_Message": "None"
},
{
  "MonitoringState": "disabled",
  "State_Code": 16,
  "State_Name": "running",
  "EbsOptimized": false,
  "EnaSupport": true,
  "AllocateStorage": 103547,
  "SourceDestCheck": true,
  "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
  "SriovNetSupport": "None",
  "StateReason_Code": "None",
  "StateReason_Message": "None"
}
]
```

What would be the best way of going about this. I have looked into `.reduce` but the examples show only adding the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce is the way to go yet:

```
let total = arr.reduce((total, obj) => {
    return total += obj.AllocateStorage
}, 0);
```